# Raspberry pi wpa_supplicant can't connect on a specific wifi. CTRL-EVENT-ASSOC-REJECT status_code = 16

Tags: wireless-networking, raspberry-pi, wifi-configuration, wpa-supplicant, wpa

I'm having trouble connecting to a specific wifi using raspberry pi. Here is the output when I check `/var/log/syslog`:

```
Jun 19 09:44:52 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[447]: wlan0: Trying to associate with 86:2a:a8:2d:35:ea (SSID='XXXX Wi-Fi' freq=2462 MHz)
Jun 19 09:44:52 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[447]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-ASSOC-REJECT status_code=16
Jun 19 09:44:52 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[447]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=1 ssid="XXXX Wi-Fi" auth_failures=6 duration=90 reason=CONN_FAILED
```

But when I connect to other wifi, it successfully connects:

```
Jun 19 09:45:24 raspberrypi dhcpcd[437]: wlan0: adding address fe80::c6af:a739:b4bb:4d62
Jun 19 09:45:24 raspberrypi kernel: [    5.610985] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Jun 19 09:45:24 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[438]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv6 with address fe80::c6af:a739:b4bb:4d62.
Jun 19 09:45:24 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[438]: New relevant interface wlan0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Jun 19 09:45:24 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[438]: Registering new address record for fe80::c6af:a739:b4bb:4d62 on wlan0.*.
Jun 19 09:45:24 raspberrypi dhcpcd[437]: wlan0: waiting for carrier
Jun 19 09:45:24 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[565]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=USER type=COUNTRY alpha2=PH
Jun 19 09:46:56 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[565]: wlan0: Trying to associate with 40:ee:dd:a9:96:94 (SSID='YYYY Wi-Fi' freq=2457 MHz)
Jun 19 09:46:56 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[565]: wlan0: Associated with 40:ee:dd:a9:96:94
Jun 19 09:46:56 raspberrypi kernel: [   98.377088] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
Jun 19 09:46:56 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[565]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=COUNTRY_IE type=COUNTRY alpha2=PH
Jun 19 09:46:56 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[565]: wlan0: WPA: Key negotiation completed with 40:ee:dd:a9:96:94 [PTK=CCMP GTK=TKIP]
Jun 19 09:46:56 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[565]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 40:ee:dd:a9:96:94 completed [id=3 id_str=]
Jun 19 09:46:56 raspberrypi dhcpcd[607]: wlan0: carrier acquired
Jun 19 09:46:56 raspberrypi dhcpcd[607]: wlan0: IAID eb:ed:a2:e2
Jun 19 09:46:57 raspberrypi dhcpcd[607]: wlan0: rebinding lease of 192.168.43.166
Jun 19 09:46:57 raspberrypi kernel: [   99.230155] IPv6: wlan0: IPv6 duplicate address fe80::c6af:a739:b4bb:4d62 detected!
Jun 19 09:46:57 raspberrypi dhcpcd[607]: wlan0: soliciting an IPv6 router
Jun 19 09:47:01 raspberrypi dhcpcd[607]: wlan0: NAK: from 192.168.16.254
Jun 19 09:47:01 raspberrypi dhcpcd[607]: wlan0: soliciting a DHCP lease
Jun 19 09:47:03 raspberrypi dhcpcd[607]: wlan0: offered 192.168.16.80 from 192.168.16.254
Jun 19 09:47:08 raspberrypi dhcpcd[607]: wlan0: leased 192.168.16.80 for 259200 seconds
Jun 19 09:47:08 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[438]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv4 with address 192.168.16.80.
Jun 19 09:47:08 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[438]: New relevant interface wlan0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Jun 19 09:47:08 raspberrypi dhcpcd[607]: wlan0: adding route to 192.168.16.0/24
Jun 19 09:47:08 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[438]: Registering new address record for 192.168.16.80 on wlan0.IPv4.
Jun 19 09:47:08 raspberrypi dhcpcd[607]: wlan0: adding default route via 192.168.16.254
Jun 19 09:47:10 raspberrypi ntpd[637]: Listen normally on 4 wlan0 192.168.16.80 UDP 123
```

Here is the output of `lsb_release -a`:

```
Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 8.0 (jessie)
Release:    8.0
Codename:   jessie
```

Output of `uname -a`:

```
Linux raspberrypi 4.9.35-v7+ #1014 SMP Fri Jun 30 14:47:43 BST 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

I've been searching this for quite a while now and I can't seem to find a working solution. The possible problem in this case would be the router or access point, but in my smartphone, I was able to connect to "XXXX Wi-Fi". So for now I'm out of ideas. Any help would be gladly appreciated.

Comment: It could be that there is a problem with the space in the SSID. Does the same happen with other access points?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, and [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/140525/29248) helped. In other words, I did

```
rmmod brcmfmac 
modprobe brcmfmac roamoff=1 feature_disable=0x82000
```

And then `wpa_supplicant` as normal, and it connected.